# Is it possible to learn Azure without having an Azure subscription?

Tags: azure

I want to up-skill myself and thinking og learning Azure. But I don't have an Azure subscription. What can I do here? Are there any tools? Simulators? etc.

Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 1):

Options are:

- Some Azure services have a free tier.
- You can sign up for a 1 month trial with $200 credit.
- Visual Studio Dev Essentials (free) gives you a $25/month credit (for 12 months). https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-dev-essentials-vs.aspx
- If you have MSDN you get $50/month or $100/month of credit depending on your MSDN level.

Comment: Azure SDK comes with an emulator that provides /some/ emulation.. Azure platform is huge, so first pick what technology you're interested in, than it might be easier to suggest how to learn it free